# Improving performance while looping over data.table with set

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I wonder if there is a better way to code the following to improve the performance.

My real data set has 120k id's with each 25 rows.

I would like to apply an exponential forecast rowise

```
library(data.table)

#dummy data set
dt <- data.table(
  ID = rep(c("A","B"), each=5),
  Value = abs(round(rnorm(10)*10))
  )

#Initialize column and value for 1st row
dt[, SES := 0]

#split by ID into list to loop over with lapply
dt <- split(dt, dt$ID) 

#function to loop with
alpha <- 0.3
loop_function <- function(x) {
  for(i in 2L:5L) {
    set(x, i, "SES", round(x[i, alpha * Value] + x[i-1L, (1L - alpha) * SES], 0))
    }
    return(x)
  }

#apply function to list elements and bind result
dt <- lapply(dt, loop_function)
dt <- rbindlist(dt)
```

Comment: Computing recursive sequences is always a bit tricky performance-wise. Often your best bet is to see if someone already implemented that computation in C. Here `?HoltWinters` might be relevant for doing exponential smoothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be much faster:

```
library(data.table)

#dummy data set
dt <- data.table(
  ID = rep(c("A","B"), each=5),
  Value = abs(round(rnorm(10)*10))
)

#Initialize column and value for 1st row
dt[, SES := 0]
# Create index and iterate over it
dt[, idx:= rowid(ID)]
for(i in 2:max(dt$idx))
{
  prev <- dt[idx==(i-1L), SES]
  dt[idx==i, SES:= {
    round(alpha * Value + (1L - alpha) * prev, 0)
  }]
}
```

It is in the end pretty similar to your idea, meaning it iterates over indexes (2:5L) but in an optimised,  data.table way. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Yep, much, much faster! Interesting approach. Thanks